# Connection.createArrayOf throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to use `Connection.createArrayOf` method to create a `java.sql.Array` to use in a prepared statement, but all of the following implementations throw ***Feature Not Supported Exception***

Is there no implementation of this method? Is it deprecated? Is there any other way to initialize `java.sql.Array`? Or have I imported the wrong package?

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl:

```java
  public Array createArrayOf(String typeName, Object[] elements) throws SQLException {
    try {
      throw SQLError.createSQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    } catch (CJException var4) {
      throw SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(var4, this.getExceptionInterceptor());
    }
  }
```

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper:

```java
  public Array createArrayOf(String typeName, Object[] elements) throws SQLException {
    try {
      this.checkClosed();

      try {
        return this.mc.createArrayOf(typeName, elements);
      } catch (SQLException var5) {
        this.checkAndFireConnectionError(var5);
        return null;
      }
    } catch (CJException var6) {
      throw SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(var6, super.exceptionInterceptor);
    }
  }
```

com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection:

```java
  public Array createArrayOf(String var1, Object[] var2) throws SQLException {
    try {
      return super.delegate.createArrayOf(var1, var2);
    } catch (SQLException var4) {
      throw this.checkException(var4);
    }
  }
```

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ha.MultiHostMySQLConnection:

```java
  public Array createArrayOf(String typeName, Object[] elements) throws SQLException {
    try {
      return this.getActiveMySQLConnection().createArrayOf(typeName, elements);
    } catch (CJException var4) {
      throw SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(var4, this.getExceptionInterceptor());
    }
  }
```

Comment: _"Is it deprecated?"_, no it is a feature that is not supported by the driver (nor the database). Maybe instead present the actual problem you're trying to solve, instead of a solution idea that is not viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue for a while but then, I chose to use [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html). You can use [MapSqlParameterSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/MapSqlParameterSource.html) to directly map Collections in your ***IN*** query.

```java
  public List<SomeClass> getSomeRecords(List<Integer> someIds, Integer someId) {
    String sql =
        "SELECT * FORM some_table st WHERE st.a IN (:someIds) AND st.b = :someId;";

    Map<String, Object> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
    paramsMap.put("someIds", someIds);
    paramsMap.put("someId", someId);

    SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource(paramsMap);
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    RowMapper<SomeClass> rowMapper = new NestedRowMapper<>(SomeClass.class);
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, parameters, rowMapper);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support ARRAY data types.  However, as you've tagged `spring-data-jpa` in this question, you can write your query methods to take a List and let Spring handle it.

e.g.

```
List<SomeClass> findBySomeFieldIn(List<Integer> ids);
```

Or, here's a simple prepared statement built with a list of Integer in an `IN` statement.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();

String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field IN (%s)",
    ints.stream()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
```

If your list had 1,2,3,4 in it, this would generate SQL that reads

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```